# uwp directx and c# development

Tags: c#, uwp, bluetooth-lowenergy, sharpdx, lumia

I'm working on a `UWP` **C#** Bluetooth application with 3d representation view.
(of the hand and fingers will receive sensors ST microelectronic WESU)

For the moment, I used windows phone 8 application (desktop and Windows phone) for Bluetooth with the ti sensor tag and `DirectX` example.

Now I arrived to read computed quaternion from the stmicro wesu sensor with a custom UWP BLE example (originally present in the Windows SDK).

But now that it works fine with **ble /sharpdx /uwp** and **Windows 10**. But when I tried now to execute the application on **Lumia 640**, I have an exception.

The issue is that it uses `DirectX` 9 and it is not supported in `UWP` by sharp dx.

The sharp dx team confirmed me that `UWP` doesn't work with `DirectX` 9 (core.net if I remember correctly).

I tried to downgrade the version used for the pixel shader and vertax shader as below but it doesn't do the job.

so my question is how can I arrive to run `DirectX` 9 Under `UWP` on the **Lumia 640**?

```
//
using (var vertexShaderByteCode = ShaderBytecode.CompileFromFile("vertexShader.hlsl", "main", "vs_4_0_level_9_1", ShaderFlags.None))
{
    vertexShader = new D3D11.VertexShader(this.device,vertexShaderByteCode);
    inputSignature = new ShaderSignature(vertexShaderByteCode);
}

//
using (var pixelShaderByteCode = ShaderBytecode.CompileFromFile("pixelShader.hlsl", "main", "ps_4_0_level_9_1", ShaderFlags.None))
{
    pixelShader = new D3D11.PixelShader(this.device , pixelShaderByteCode);
}
```

[image: triangle initialisation with pixel shader and vertex shader]

Comment: Lumia 640 only supports DirectX 11 according to this link (https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/mobile/phone/lumia640/specifications/). So it just doesn't support DirectX 9. Are you sure your problem is with the shader bytecode (its normally backward compatible and very few features are deprecated in HLSL) and not with the SharpDX libraries you are referencing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i agreee with you, it's just about de shader

**vs_4_0_level_9_1**
**ps_4_0_level_9_1**
and

using (D3D11.Device defaultDevice = new D3D11.Device(D3D.DriverType.Hardware, D3D11.DeviceCreationFlags.**None**))

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5SOn.jpg)